# in spaCy, are 'en' and 'en_core_web' models different?

Tags: nlp, spacy

I was reading [this article](https://medium.com/@dudsdu/named-entity-recognition-for-unstructured-documents-c325d47c7e3a) about spaCy, and the author mentioned `en` and `en_core_web` models. I went through some content on spaCy's site, but didn't seem to find explanation on the relationship between these two.

I have been using the `en` model from the installation `python -m spacy download en`, I know that there is a separate install for `en_core_web`.

So are these two models different? If so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are short names for models in spaCy, and `en` is simply a shortcut for `en_core_web_sm`,  where `sm` stands for small, there are also `md` and `lg`, for [a middle and a large one](https://spacy.io/models/en), respectively. You can find the full list of shortcuts here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/explosion/spacy-models/master/shortcuts-v2.json